# Why when setting height to 10% to fixed header there is an inconsistent distance between this and the main?

Tags: html, css

Something strange happens if I give percentage values to my fixed header and main div.

When I use `50px` as value for the height of the header and `50px` as margin-top for the main area everything works fine.

But when I want these values to be `10%` then there is an inconsistent distance between the header and the main:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}

main {
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  My Header
</header>
<main>
  Mainarea here!
</main>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/L7sroo4m/

Has somebody an explanation for this?

Comment: margin-top/bottom: x% or padding-top/bottom: X%  refer to parent's width : see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties and if you add some collapsing-margins effect, you may be confused at first I may post this as an answer if you wish

Comment: i am still confused... As far as I see both elements have the same parent which implies that the percentage value should affect the same absolute value.

Comment: height:10% and margin-top:10% are not the same. resize window and see those 10% update  for the margin value. element set in absolute or fixed position are off the flux, but you could use here : `body:before {content:'';height:10vh;display:block;}` instead an average margin-top:10%; on main . notice that margin-top:10vh; will work. https://jsfiddle.net/L7sroo4m/1/

Comment: Trying to resize helped a lot for my understanding. As far as I observed it, `margin-top: 10%` refers to the width of the browser and `height: 10%` refers to the height of the browser. the position values didn't affect that.
Is there another way to use relative values? Can I refer to a certain value?

Comment: does vh units meets your requirement  as i commented earlier ?(10vh = 10% of browser's height)  100vw is 100% of browser's width.

Comment: ah sorry i read over that. this definitely solve my issue :)
thank you! how do I mention that this is a solution?

Comment: You can add an  answer yourself to your question, mention the sources to explain what went wrong &  give the solution you have used ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCyrillus gave me the hints to answer this now:

The problem is that the percentage value of height refers to the parent height but the percentage value of margin-top refers to the parent width.

The solution is to not use percentage values but using viewport units `x vh` which refers to the height of the viewport.

In other words just replace `10%` by `10vh` in my example and everything works fine.

there is an example of viewport unit
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport_small.html

Answer (score 0):

Your html and your body tag do not have a specific height and width, for starters u have to add this:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

here is the full css:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
main {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

i made main `position: absolute` and gave it top instead of margin because margin will make the body have overflow on the bottom unless you do `body{height: 90%;}` which is bad practice because the header is in the body

Comment: I already had the solution to use top in both css declarations but this leads to another strange result in further versions of my layout.

Comment: I will help you fix them if you would like. Id say i am experienced a bit

Comment: Just whenever u get a problem reply here

Comment: okay... my intention is to build a mobile view. I want a fixed header and footer. So when I use for the main area `top: 10%;` and `bottom: 10%;` `overflow-y: scroll;`then iPhones will always show the safari menu additionally.
Moreover there is a bug when you start scrolling in the wrong direction the scrolling bar get stuck and you can't scroll for a few seconds